# Is it possible to add a left bar button item with multiple lines of text

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I would like to add a label in the left bar button item with multiple lines of text. the height of the navigation bar will be changed according to the height of the label.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `UIBarButtonItem ` with init(customView:) initialize with may be UIlabel with multiline text. Never tried it. but should work

Answer (score 1):

- You can add view in left bar button item and add label inside it and give the label constraints as you want to it's superview.
- if you want to increase navigation bar height, You can add space in prompt like below image but you can't increase it throw navigationBar.frame, it doesn't work with me. [image]